# How to parse through email and extract ONLY HTML text dates

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-apps-script, gmail

I currently have this code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


function getEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Reservation confirmed");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var row = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m=0; m < messages.length; m++) {   
      sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(messages[m].getPlainBody());
      row++;
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Load Emails", functionName: "getEmails"} ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Email", menuEntries);
}
```

It extracts the body of certain emails I have tagged. I need help writing a code to then sift through the HTML body of the email and extract dates that are formatted as: ‌A‌p‌r‌ ‌0‌1‌,‌ ‌2‌0‌1‌8‌. Jun 21, 2018. etc

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974647/copy-push-data-from-array-into-a-sheet-range-one-row-at-a-time-using-google-apps/48975171#48975171

Comment: Well, where is the code you have that is not working correctly? You want to apply a multi-line regular expression ("regex"), so I recommend you use a regex testing website, several example emails, and develop a pattern that will work.